# loading external URL on Dashboard Content

Tags: angularjs

I want to load URL( external URL 'http://google.com') in  Dashboard content,I  tried with this code

```
 .state('app.urlloading', {
    url: '/url-loading',
    controller:function($window){

      $window.location.href = 'https://google.com';

    },
    templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/url-loading.html'
  })
```

1) Is it possible to load a  external URL in Dashboard content ?, If I click a button  on  sidebar of the dashboard  only dashboard content should display the URL retaining sidebar and header, now whole dashboard is disappearing after clicking the button then redirecting  to the google page.

Comment: may you use an `iframe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change location.href, whole page changes. Static HTML usable from states that static HTML link does not matter is external or not.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="h_iframe">
    <!-- a transparent image is preferable -->
    <img class="ratio" src="http://placehold.it/16x9"/>
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WsFWhL4Y84Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<p>Please scale the "result" window to notice the effect.</p>
```

But you could use iframes like this that is what are you exactly wanting.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an `iframe`

**url-loading.html**

```
<iframe src="https://google.com"></iframe>
```

If you need to open differents url using same `template & controller` you can use a `resolver`

```
 // loading google
.state('app.urlloading', {
    url: '/url-loading-google',
    controller:'UrlLoadingCtrl'
    resolve {
        url : function(){
            return "https://www.google.com"
        }
    }
    templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/url-loading.html'
  })

 // loading twitter
.state('app.urlloading', {
    url: '/url-loading-twitter',
    controller:'UrlLoadingCtrl'
    resolve {
        url : function(){
            return "https://www.twitter.com"
        }
    }
    templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/url-loading.html'
  })
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('UrlLoadingCtrl', [ 'url', '$scope', function(url, $scope){
    $scope.url = url;
})
```

**url-loading.html**

```
<iframe src="{{url}}"></iframe>
```